# sstabloader compatibility between datastax cassandra and apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Does sstabloader work between datastax cassandra and apache cassandra?

I'm trying to copy data from dse 5.0.7 to apache 3.11.1 cassandra version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue to use it to export between Datastax Cassandra and the open source version, if they are the same versions.

Having said that, please note that DSE 5.0.7 uses Apache 3.0.11, as explained in the [release notes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html#RNdse__507). This means that you should import the data to a cluster with that version, and once that this is completed, upgrade to 3.11.1.

Disclosure: I'm not a DSE user, I don't have a way to test this.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, does sstableloader works only on same version of Cassandra. It should support based on sstable name type like   ka mb,mc right

Comment: Hi @cad , the times that I have used sstableloader, it has been always against the same version of the engine. Researching on your question, I couldn't find any restrictions on the version (other than use C* 3.0.5 for versions prior to C* 3, explained in https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html)

It seems that you should be able to use it with different versions, if the schema of the tables is the same